# Access constant in swift from Objective-C file

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, constants

I am very new to Swift. I have one hybrid project in which some classes are in Objective-C and some are Swift. I have one Constant.h file which is based with Objective-C file. In this header file have mention some constant like bellow

```
#define mainViewBgColor [UIColor colorWithRed:248.0/255.0 green:247.0/255.0 blue:247.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]
```

But problem is that i can't access this constant in Swift class. See bellow Swift code

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.backgroundColor = mainViewBgColor //Want to access liek this but this line gives me an error.
        self.loadNavigation();
    }
```

Please suggest the right way to access constants like this specifically the constant write in Objective-C.

**Note : Please consider that i have Bridging-Header.h file and i have already import the constant file into that bridge file. Even i can successfully access simple string constant.**

**Edited
Alternate Solution** : I have found the alternate solution for using constants in swift is to create new swift constant file let say SwiftConstant.swift and define the constant like bellow in this file.

```
let  mainViewBgColor = UIColor(red: 248.0/255.0, green: 247.0/255.0, blue: 247.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
```

now without importing SwiftConstant.swift file anywhere i can use the constant. i don't know this is right way or not hoping and wait for good answer.

Comment: You are already on the right track. :) Your edit is exactly how I also use constants in Swift. Although, you can't call them macros anymore. They're just constants in Swift

Answer (score 4):

It depends.

From the documentation

> **Simple Macros**
>
> Where you typically used the #define directive to define a primitive
>   constant in C and Objective-C, in Swift you use a global constant
>   instead. For example, the constant definition #define
>   FADE_ANIMATION_DURATION 0.35 can be better expressed in Swift with let
>   FADE_ANIMATION_DURATION = 0.35. **Because simple constant-like macros
>   map directly to Swift global variables, the compiler automatically
>   imports simple macros defined in C and Objective-C source files.**
>
> **Complex Macros**
>
> **Complex macros are used in C and Objective-C but have no counterpart
>   in Swift. Complex macros are macros that do not define constants,
>   including parenthesized, function-like macros.** You use complex macros
>   in C and Objective-C to avoid type-checking constraints or to avoid
>   retyping large amounts of boilerplate code. However, macros can make
>   debugging and refactoring difficult. In Swift, you can use functions
>   and generics to achieve the same results without any compromises.
>   Therefore, the complex macros that are in C and Objective-C source
>   files are not made available to your Swift code.

Source: [Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html)

Comment: Vadian i also decide to make separate constant file for Swift classes after seen this article. But, sorry for not make your answer as accepted :)